# update data which are fetched in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I have two components:

```
class FloorView extends Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dateBegin: moment(),
        dateEnd: '2018-09-30'
    }
    this.setDateBeginHandler = this.setDateBeginHandler.bind(this);
}

setDateBeginHandler(date) {
    this.setState({
        dateBegin: date
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="FloorView">
            <div className="Toolbar">
                <DatePicker2 selected={this.state.dateBegin} onChange={this.setDateBeginHandler} />
                <DatePicker className="dateBegin" />
                <DatePicker className="dateEnd" />
            </div>
            <Room dateBegin={this.state.dateBegin.format("YYYY-MM-DD")} dateEnd={this.state.dateEnd} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Circle from './Circle/Circle';
import './Room.css';

class Room extends Component {
setDesks(floor) {
    // fetch call which accesses this.props.dateBegin to fetch data
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setDesks(1);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        ....
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

If in FloorView the handler setDateBeginHandler() is triggered, the property 'dateBegin' in Room component is changed. How can I call my setDesks() to fetch data again? Until now the change has no impact.

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get it yet. Can you show me code and tell what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for your question is already available in Official React Document: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops . I will take out the exactly part which you actually need:

> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate lifecycle instead.

According to the document, whenever you need to perform API calls in response to a change in props, use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle hook.

For example (I also take this example from [React Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)):

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Based on the example, re-writing it in order to fit your own application logic.

Hopefully, it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you check the props change in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.dateBegin !== this.props. dateBegin) {
    // your methods go here ...
  }
}
```

Check the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

If the Room component had its own state you could also use `getDerivedStateFromProps()` method to track the prop change and to update Room component state due to these changes. Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `setDesks` is updating state, you can avoid extra redraws from `componentDidUpdate` (which will render twice) if you do a small refactor so `setDesks` takes a couple of extra values (start, end)

Then you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` on Room

An example would be:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.dateBegin !== nextProps.dateBegin) {
    this.setDesks(1, nextProps.dateBegin, nextProps.dateEnd)
  }
}
```

Comment: the `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle hook is going to be deprecated in the future, according to the official react document: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops . They said "this lifecycle method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies".

Comment: Thanks. I was aware a few methods were getting deprecated, but wasn't aware `componentWillReceiveProps` was one of them. I've upvoted your answer.